# Updating a Confluence Page with HTTP Post

Tags: java, http, post, confluence

I'm working on integrating Five9 (a cloud calling platform) with Atlassian Confluence.  The only option I have for connectors are simple HTTP POST methods.

The basic requirement here is to get a few basic values into Confluence - Agent.user_name and Call.number.

Confluence has many options for accepting data, the best of which is probably passing a JSON object through their REST API ([link](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest)).

Is there any way I can stringify the entire JSON request into the URL?

It was also recommended to me to just host a "middleman" site to accept the POST request and pass the value on to Confluence via typical Javascript, but web development isn't really my primary area of expertise so I don't have much of a plan in way of hosting the site (it would have to be only accessible on the LAN).

Besides those two options, are there any other recommendations or approaches?  Maybe something obvious I'm missing?